# How to get raw JSON message from request and HTTP status code from response

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot application. We have a requirement to store raw JSON request and HTTP response code to store in database as part of processing the request.

We are able to intercept request in a class that extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter. This class has implemented afterBodyRead method to get body of the request. Unfortunately there is no way to get the raw JSON request in this method.

Similarly we have another class that has implemented ResponseBodyAdvice to intercept response. In beforeBodyWrite method, response status code is not available.

Comment: Add code to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple servlet filter:

```
@Component
public class JsonFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        // Log JSON request

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        // Log JSON response and HTTP Status code
    }

    // other methods 
}
```

Read more about filters and Spring Boot here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter